# Date Field Mask Not Working

Tags: coldfusion, datefield

This is very frustrating. I am using `cfinput datefield` and `mask="MM/DD/YYYY"` and its not working. If it is `cfinput text` and `mask="MM/DD/YYYY"` it works perfect. I do not want to only have a textbox though I would like to keep the calendar that the date field gives you... The issue is when they use the calendar it is in the correct format MM/DD/YYYY but if the user just types in the date into the textbox without using the calendar the user can type whatever they desire.. (122334435) which obviously is unacceptable. Any ideas or workarounds anyone may be aware of?

Works:

```
    <cfform name="foo">
    <cfinput 
      type="text" 
      name="test" 
      validate="eurodate" 
      mask="99/99/9999" 
      validateat="onblur" />
    <input type="submit">
    </cfform>
```

Does Not Work:

```
    <cfform name="foo">
    <cfinput 
      type="datefield" 
      name="test" 
      validate="eurodate" 
      mask="MM/DD/YYYY" 
      validateat="onblur" />
    <input type="submit">
    </cfform>
```

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/26286518/1636917. As I said before, the `datefield` type is specific to Flash forms. That is why it does not work for you.

Comment: Do you see an answer to fix it?

Comment: It can't be fixed. It is only for Flash forms.

Comment: Datefields? Why does it work everything but Mask then?

Comment: You think there isn't anyway around that? No JavaScript Jquery Nothing?

Comment: Of course you can use JavaScript / jQuery but that has nothing to do with cfinput. This is just another example of the poor implementation of the cfxxx form tags and why you should not use them. Absolutely use jQuery.

Comment: I am really starting to dislike CF

Comment: @Bauer you should learn to write JavaScript yourself rather than relying on a crap implementation built into the language. I'm not aware of any other language that has the UI bloat built in. If that's why you dislike CF you won't like any language.

Comment: There are dozens of jQuery plug-ins that will help you do exactly what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: To back up Matt's point:  http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/1/23/Im-not-going-to-tell-you-to-stop-using-ColdFusion-UI-tags-anymore

Comment: hahaha yes I do need to learn it... it seems like everything evolves around javascript or jquery. Seems to be very handy if you understand it.

Comment: I understand your frustration. We have all been there. You start out using those cfxxx tags and think wow that was easy. But as soon as you need a little bit more complexity they stop being easy and in fact become more problematic. Definitely learn jQuery or the like and your pages will be better for it. You should find lots of examples out there.

Comment: Is Jquery hard to set up?

Comment: Its just a download and you call it right?

Comment: Yep, you download it and include it and then it works. Pretty simple.

Comment: any idea of which one to download? aren't there many with many add ons?

Comment: also should I end up deleting this question since there is no real answer to this?

Comment: lol or should I change it asking for a jquery script for it hahaha

Comment: Please do not open multiple threads for the *same* question. If you need to add more details, just "edit" the existing one ;-) This thread should be deleted because it is a duplicate of the other one.

Comment: See [coldfusion ui the right way](https://github.com/cfjedimaster/ColdFusion-UI-the-Right-Way) to get you started. This is exactly why they started that project. Then when you have specific coding questions come back and ask.

Comment: Doesn't eurodate use periods to separate the date components?

Comment: I notice you are validating onblur.  Bad idea.  The user can clear the alert and submit the form anyway.  Much better to validate onsubmit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added an answer to the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26286518/1636917) that was originally opened regarding this same issue. I will post a bit here as well since users may find this question and not the other one. Or you could delete this question.

I believe the problem is that the `mask` attribute on the `<cfinput type="datefield" ...` code only works when using Flash forms - [documentation reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0ffd8-7ffe.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0ffd8-7fe7).

I have ***emphasized the text*** from that documentation below:

> **Masking cfcalendar and datefield input**
>
> In the cfcalendar tag and the ***Flash format datefield input control***, you use the following masks to determine the format of the output. You can use uppercase or lowercase characters in the mask:
>
> ...
>
> The following pattern specifies that the ***Flash form*** sends the date selected using a datefield input control to ColdFusion as text in the format 04/29/2004:
>
> `<cfinput name="startDate" type="datefield" label="date:" mask="mm/dd/yyyy"/>`

Since you are not using a Flash form the mask is not working for you. You could try switching to a regular `<cfinput type="text" ...` input and change your mask to something like `"99/99/9999"`. That would give you the correct format but the user could still enter invalid dates so you would need additional code to catch that.

This is just another example of why using the built-in ColdFusion UI tags is not a good idea. They work for very simple examples but when you need more customization they fail you. You would be better off to use a JavaScript library (like jQuery) for client side validation. Adobe's own [Ben Forta acknowledged this several years ago](http://forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2012/11/25/When-Using-ColdFusion-No-Longer-Makes-Sense). And the [ColdFusion-UI-the-Right-Way project](https://github.com/cfjedimaster/ColdFusion-UI-the-Right-Way) was started because of this as well.

**EDIT**

On the other question that was posted Adam pointed out [another reference in the ColdFusion documentation](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfinput#cfinput-History) that reinforces my point. I have ***emphasized the text*** from that documentation below:

> **Masking input data**
>
> In HTML and Flash forms, the mask attribute controls the format of data that can be entered into a text field or that is selected in a datefield input control calendar. ***In HTML format, it does not prevent users from typing a date that does not follow the mask into a datefield input control.*** You can combine masking and validation on a field.